# Check how long is pressed the left mouse button

Tags: c#, wpf, events, time, buttonclick

How can I check how long I click the right mouse button, and than handle some events from the click?

For example: I have an `ListViewOnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event and a `ListViewOnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` event, now I want to check how long I actually did press the left mouse button - **without a timer**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use to DateTime vars in each of your events:

```
DateTime start,end;
```

in Down Event:

```
start=DateTime.Now;
```

in Up event:

```
 end=DateTime.Now;
 TimeSpan difference = end - start;
 double secs = difference.TotalSecs;
```

Comment: Thanks. And now, how can i handle in the ListViewOnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event the PreviewMouseMove event?